# Correct term to say that a number divides another number "evenly"?

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, language-use

This is something that has continued to bother me in general, and recently I had multiple occasions where saying something like "2 divides 14 evenly" has confused students, They expected the result to be an even number, not $7$.  I can't seem to find the concise word/wording for saying that a number divides another without a remainder?  I would like to start using this instead of "evenly" for my students' benefit

Comment: Maybe 'exactly' could be used. Many students use equally and evenly interchangeably

Comment: 2 divides 14 with remainder 0; 2 is a divisor of 14; 2 is a factor of 14; 14 is a multiple of 2; 14 divided by 2 is a whole number. Etc. (Or you could explain precisely what you mean by "evenly" in this context.)

Comment: How about "with no remainder"?

Comment: I like "m is a divisor/factor of n", because this makes it clear that divisibility is a relation, not a process. (Phrases like "m divides n without remainder" could make it sound like m is actively doing something to n, rather than having some preexisting relation to n.)

Comment: It seems to me the problem is the commonality between the words "evenly" and "even" here.  My suggestion would be "cleanly", so "2 divides 14 cleanly" (i.e. there's no mess, no remainders).  Although I will say that stating things this way is confusing on the face of things--I think students would be more accustomed to "14 can be divided into 2 cleanly".

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what level of Mathematics you are teaching? This will greatly assist with the language to use. For example, for a more advanced number theory course, saying "2 divides 14" would be preferable over say "14 is a multiple of 2", which would perhaps be more preferable at the high school level.

Comment: @DanielHast This precise concern of yours manifests when elementary school students (and teachers) are learning about this topic: Specifically, divisibility is viewed in terms of being an action or process (in the sense of Dubinsky's APOS theory) rather than structurally. See, specifically, the work of Zazkis and Campbell ([**example**](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=xuePS8EAAAAJ&citation_for_view=xuePS8EAAAAJ:9yKSN-GCB0IC)).

Answer (score 4):

Make it clear to your students to begin with that when it comes to divisibility, we are only ever interested in whole number divisibility. Otherwise, of course any non-zero number 'divides' any other number! (I assume you're working with the reals).

So it will then suffice to simply say

> 2 divides 14